# Handling contract; make functions in classes of sub packages private

Tags: java, class, architecture

I want to create a module with 2 classes "accessable" from the outside => public. 
Now, I have several further classes, that shall be stored in sub package and that I would like not to be public, but accessable by my class.

e.g.:
supermod:

```
-> App.java
-> AppInstance.java
-> communication
    -> MQTTClient.java
    -> FileHandler.java
-> aifunctions
    -> AIFileList.java
```

No, how can I set a function inside AIFileList.java, that it can be called from AppInstance, but not from any class further above?

Is there no way to define "Module private" or "Module protected" functions?